# Add data entered in a cloud page form into a data extension in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, form

Is it possible to have a custom form write the results into a data extension? The form will have a Name field,Event Type (drop-down) and a Promotion Type (Checkbox). I have a data extension setup with those fields already.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible. You didn't specify where your custom form would reside, so I'm going to use a pair of CloudPages for a **BARE-BONES** (i.e., no fancy JS) example. We'll need:

1. A page that contains the form
2. A page that receives/processes the data
3. A data extension that stores the data
4. AMPscript [Sites functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm)
5. AMPscript [Data Extension functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertdata.htm)

The form page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="https://my-processing-page" method="POST">
      Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      Event Type:<br>
      <select name="eventtype">
        <option value="foo">Foo</option>
        <option value="bar">Bar</option>
      </select><br>
      Promotion Type:<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="promotype" value="baz"> Baz
      <br>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The processing page

```
%%[
var @eventType,
    @insertData,
    @name,
    @promoType

/* store incoming form values to AMPscript variables */
set @name = RequestParameter('name')
set @eventType = RequestParameter('eventtype')
set @promoType = RequestParameter('promotype')

if not Empty(@name)
  and not Empty(@eventType)
  and not Empty(@promoType) then

  set @insertData = InsertData(
    'My Custom Form Data',
    'Name', @name,
    'Event Type', @eventType,
    'Promotion Type', @promoType
  )

  if (@insertData == 1) then
]%%

Data was successfully saved.

%%[
  else
]%%

Could not save data.

%%[
  endif
else
]%%

All form fields required, please go back.

%%[
endif
]%%
```

While this example should work, there is much **MUCH** more to be done still (e.g., form validation, applying web security best practices, etc.), but this can get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this.The form will live on a cloud page like the example you provided. There is a confirmation/summary of the form built into the form so the processing page will just be a "Thank you for submitting" so does that mean this ampscript should live in the form instead of the processing page?

**This is my confirmation button**
 <div class="text-center">
      <button id="editInfo" class="btn" type="button">Edit Info</button>
      <a id="confirmation" class="btn btn-red" type="submit" href="http://thank-you-page" role="button">Confirm</a>
     </div>

Comment: @Greg the AMPscript will live in a separate processing page that also, in the example above, plays the role of a "thank you" page. If you wanted everything to occur within the confines of a single page, a separate processing page to execute AMPscript will still be required, but you could employ JavaScript to submit the form asynchronousy. That is beyond the scope of the bare-bones example provided.